# Python: Cumulative insertion of values in a sparse matrix (lil_matrix) due to repeated indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

my situation is as follows:

I have an array of results, say
`S = np.array([2,3,10,-1,12,1,2,4,4])`, which I would like to insert in the last row of a `scipy.sparse.lil`_matrix `M` according to an array of column indices with possibly repeated elements (with no specific pattern), e.g.:
`j = np.array([3,4,5,14,15,16,3,4,5])`.

When column indices are repeated, the sum of their corresponding values in `S` should be inserted in the matrix `M`. Thus, in the example above, results `[4,7,14]` should be placed in columns `[3,4,5]` of the last row of `M`. In other words, I would like to achieve something like:

`M[-1,j] = np.array([2+2,3+4,10+4,-1,12,1])`.

Calculation speed is very important for my program, such that I should avoid using loops. Looking forward to your clever solutions! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That kind of summation is the normal behavior for `sparse` matrices, especially in the `csr` format.

define the 3 input arrays:

```
In [408]: S = np.array([2,3,10,-1,12,1,2,4,4])
In [409]: j=np.array([3,4,5,14,15,16,3,4,5])
In [410]: i=np.ones(S.shape,int)
```

The `coo` format takes those 3 arrays, as is, without change

```
In [411]: c0=sparse.coo_matrix((S,(i,j)))
In [412]: c0.data
Out[412]: array([ 2,  3, 10, -1, 12,  1,  2,  4,  4])
```

But when converted to `csr` format, it sums repeated indices:

```
In [413]: c1=c0.tocsr()
In [414]: c1.data
Out[414]: array([ 4,  7, 14, -1, 12,  1], dtype=int32)
In [415]: c1.A
Out[415]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  4,  7, 14,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1, 12,  1]], dtype=int32)
```

That summation is also done when converting the `coo` to dense or array, `c0.A`.

and when converting to `lil`:

```
In [419]: cl=c0.tolil()
In [420]: cl.data
Out[420]: array([[], [4, 7, 14, -1, 12, 1]], dtype=object)
In [421]: cl.rows
Out[421]: array([[], [3, 4, 5, 14, 15, 16]], dtype=object)
```

`lil_matrix` does not accept the `(data,(i,j))` input directly, so you have to go through `coo` if that is your target.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html

> By default when converting to CSR or CSC format, duplicate (i,j) entries will be summed together. This facilitates efficient construction of finite element matrices and the like. (see example)

To do this as an insertion in an existing `lil` use an intermediate `csr`:

```
In [443]: L=sparse.lil_matrix((3,17),dtype=S.dtype)
In [444]: L[-1,:]=sparse.csr_matrix((S,(np.zeros(S.shape),j)))
In [445]: L.A
Out[445]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  4,  7, 14,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1, 12,  1]])
```

This statement is faster than the one using `csr_matrix`;

```
L[-1,:]=sparse.coo_matrix((S,(np.zeros(S.shape),j)))
```

Examine `L.__setitem__` if you are really worried about speed.  Off hand it looks like it normally converts a sparse matrix to array

```
L[-1,:]=sparse.coo_matrix((S,(np.zeros(S.shape),j))).A
```

takes the same time.  With a small test case like this, the overhead of creating an intermediate matrix can swamp any time spent adding these duplicate indices.

In general, inserting or appending values to an existing sparse matrix is slow, regardless of whether you do this summation or not.  Where possible it is best to create the `data`, `i` and `j` arrays for the whole matrix first, and then make the sparse matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful hints! Hopefully the conversion process to csr_matrix is not too expensive.

Comment: I time tested a few variations.  Using `coo_matrix` is faster than `csr_matrix`.

Comment: Perfect! In a later stage, I will try to build the matrix at once in csr format by using data, i, and j arrays as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) that maps the M column indices to their value and use the `map` function to update this defaultdict, like so:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int) #Use your array type here
def f(j, s):
    d[j] += s
map(f, j, S)
M[-1, d.keys()] = d.values() #keys and values are always in the same order
```

Instead of `map`, you can use `filter` if you don't want to create a list of `None` uselessly:

```
d = defaultdict(int) #Use your array type here
def g(e):
    d[e[1]] += S[e[0]]
filter(g, enumerate(j))
M[-1, d.keys()] = d.values() #keys and values are always in the same
```